# VBox NAT Network VPN

Tags: networking, ssh, virtualbox, vpn, nat

I wasn't quite sure whether to post this in a networking forum, or here, but I chose here since it is more software related rather than networking related. Basically, I want to be able to remotely VPN into a VBox NAT network.

I drew a little diagram of what I am trying to accomplish.

[image: Drawing]

If you are unfamiliar with the symbols, the rectangle with arrows is a switch, and the circle with arrows is a router. :)

I want to be able to SSH to each of the machines, but a bridged connection is not an option, as I need for the VM's to be sorta separate from the rest of the network. I was thinking of maybe just putting another VM, which would have a reverse SSH connection to a VPS, however I was thinking there could be something more along the lines of Hamachi. It would be great if Teamviewer for Linux had a VPN, but of course it doesn't. The VM's are all Linux, and the computer trying to remotely connect is a Macbook Pro, if it matters.

Thank you for your help! If you need any more information, please let me know and I will gladly provide it :)

Comment: Is there a specific part of this setup you need help with?  What pieces of it do  you control?  Can you port forward through the company NAT's?

Comment: I only control the VBox NAT Network, and the remote MBP, unfortunately. Currently, I have Teamviewer installed on each VM, however I would like to move away from that and use a VPN so that I can just SSH, as I have no need for the GUI in each VM.

Comment: If you can't run a listening service behind either company NAT, you're going to need some kind of external server that can relay between the two.

Comment: Well, I do actually have a VPS that I own.

With that, I would just need a conceptual explanation of what needs to be set up, and the software required, and I would be able to figure the rest out.

Comment: You should split the question in two and just ask the first part and answer it first then look at teh second part. First part is What software do you need to set up a VPN in Linux, and what is the procedure. You may find you need this command and some port forwarding. Second part is Then you just need to know how to  do port forwarding in virtualbox. They are separate questions.